# Unauthenticated Use Exceeded for google drive api

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api

I have a laravel project in which I use google drive API. It was working fine but then I got the error:

> "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

so I again get the refresh token from oauth playground now it is working fine.
but I don't want to again and again get the refresh token manually and update in my .env file.
how can I automatically update the refresh token whenever it is expired.

the information of the client id, secret key and refresh token is saved in .env file.

the google drive file upload code is in route in web.php

```
Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("",$request->file("thing"),$name);
            $url=Storage::disk('google')->url($name);
            $details=Storage::disk("google")->getMetadata($name);
            $path=$details['path'];
```

Comment: Your request is not authorized.  Check ensure that your authorization is set correctly.  https://quantizd.com/google-drive-client-api-with-laravel/

Comment: @DaImTo it is working fine when using new token, but the problem is I have to get the new token and change it in my file again and again. I am actually not using some controller files etc, I am just using blade.php and web.php I am new to laravel and is using this just for one little purpose, I have no knowledge of laravel so cant understand that controller thing

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you already have a PHP framework that works with the Drive API. Based on that, the error informs you that the [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) flow is not correctly configured. Please check the [Drive API PHP example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php) to see a fully functional OAuth 2.0 authorization script. You can copy-paste that example to a run test, and once it's working you can just update your script to include the necessary authentication flow. Please ask me any doubts about this approach.